# addPullToRefresh function is not invoked when only one item exists

Tags: codenameone

In my code I have a scrollable container, I want to call a refresh function when the user pulls down on the container.

```
    venueList = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
    venueList.setScrollableY(true);

    venueList.addPullToRefresh(() -> {
        refresh();
    });
```

This works well when there is more then one item in the container, however, when there is only one item or less, this does not work.

The issue occurs both on the NetBeans simulator and on my ios device.

My current workaround is to add a button to the list if it is empty (after calling a web-service) named "REFRESH", with the refresh() function invoked on clicking it.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** I just tried this with tabs too with the same result:

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", new BorderLayout());
Tabs t = new Tabs();
Container mainContainer = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
mainContainer.setScrollableY(true);
mainContainer.addPullToRefresh(() -> log("Pull..."));
t.addTab("Test Tabs", mainContainer);
hi.add(CENTER, t);
hi.show();
```

[image]

Original answer below:

This worked fine for me with no elements so I'm guessing there is a different issue such as placing the container within a nested scrollable hierarchy:

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", new BorderLayout());
Container mainContainer = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
mainContainer.setScrollableY(true);
mainContainer.addPullToRefresh(() -> log("Pull..."));
hi.add(CENTER, mainContainer);
hi.show();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround, interesting, you are correct that I am not putting the container directly into the form, but rather putting it into a tab:    tabContainer = new Tabs();     ......                         tabContainer.addTab("Around Me",aroundTabicon,BoxLayout.encloseY(venueList)); Is there something specific that I need to set on the tab container level?

Comment: Is the tabs container in the center of the forms border layout? Notice that if you nest scrollable elements there might be a problem. Also notice that you might want to disable the tab swiping as that might have an impact on this behavior.

Comment: Thanks Shai, yes it is in the center and I did disable the swiping on the tab  as I am using swipable buttons within my list to get a left swipe to delete, etc... is there a specific way I should use it within the tab?

Comment: Works for me with a tabs container too, updated my answer with a sample

Answer (score 0):

@Shai, thank you for pointing me in the right direction, it indeed ended up being a nesting issue.

When I was adding my list container to the Tab container I was using the following code:

```
    tabContainer.addTab("Around Me",aroundTabicon,BoxLayout.encloseY(venueList));
```

Note that the BoxLayout.encloseY was causing the issue, I removed it and ended up with the following:

```
    tabContainer.addTab("Around Me",aroundTabicon,venueList);
```

And it seems to be working now.... thank you again.